# XML Pull Parser implementation in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xmlpullparser

Just as the title asks: are there any XML pull parser implementations in a Perl library?

I looked at [XML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/~podmaster/XML-TokeParser-0.05/TokeParser.pm), but it's nine years old! I'm sure there's something out there that is functional?

Comment: Note that while TokeParser may be nine years old, the actual parsing is done by XML::Parser, which is pretty well updated.

Comment: I'd answer your question, but it's already 3 minutes old! (seriously, what's the problem, is it buggy?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [XML::TreePuller](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML-TreePuller) - it's a hybrid tree and pull parser that's very convenient to use and also very fast. I created it to power MediaWiki::DumpFile which you can use as a real world example of how to do something with it but it also has quite a bit of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/) is a fully featured XML parser library based around the libxml2 C library - so it's really fast.  LibXML is typically used via the DOM/XPath API, but it also supports both a SAX API and and a **Pull** API via [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Reader) (which is included in the distribution).

Comment: The `XML::LibXML::Reader` module is incredibly difficult to use correctly. You need to write a lot of low-level checks to work around its quirks (treating `<a />` differently from `<a></a>`; the current token after parsing the `<a>` start tag in `<a> <b /></a>` vs `<a><b /></a>`; etc). It's basically a lexer with a stack of element names.